# You can't specify target table '...' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I want to make an update on a table with the results of a query and that records exist in the tables, my SLQ is:

UPDATE 
    reparticion 
SET 
    responsable_nombre_completo = (select CONCAT_WS(',',persona.nombre,persona.apellido) FROM persona INNER JOIN usuario on usuario.cuil = persona.cuil) 
WHERE 
    reparticion.id IN (select persona.reparticion_id FROM persona INNER JOIN usuario on usuario.cuil = persona.cuil INNER JOIN reparticion on reparticion.id = persona.reparticion_id);

but I get the following error:

You can't specify target table 'reparticion' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1):

The better approach would be to use `join update` instead of `sub-queries`.

```
update reparticion r
join persona p on p.reparticion_id = r.id
join usuario u on u.cuil = p.cuil
set r.responsable_nombre_completo = CONCAT_WS(',',p.nombre,p.apellido)
```